Updating RecyclerView Data When Database is Updated in Android
I'm working on an Android project where I need to update the RecyclerView data whenever the database is updated.
I have two options for where to call the database operations:

In the MainActivity
In the RecyclerView adapter class itself

I'm not sure which approach is better in terms of best practices and maintainability.
Approach 1: Database Operations in MainActivity
// MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var recyclerViewAdapter: TaskRecyclerViewAdapter
    private lateinit var db: DatabaseHandler

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = DatabaseHandler(this)
        recyclerViewAdapter = TaskRecyclerViewAdapter(db.getAllTasks())

        // Setup RecyclerView
        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recyclerView)
        recyclerView.adapter = recyclerViewAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }

    private fun addTask(task: TaskModel) {
        db.addTask(task)
        recyclerViewAdapter.setTaskList(db.getAllTasks())
    }

    private fun updateTask(task: TaskModel) {
        db.updateTask(task.id.toLong(), task.taskText)
        recyclerViewAdapter.setTaskList(db.getAllTasks())
    }

    private fun deleteTask(taskId: Int) {
        db.deleteTask(taskId.toLong())
        recyclerViewAdapter.setTaskList(db.getAllTasks())
    }
}

Approach 2: Database Operations in RecyclerView Adapter
// TaskRecyclerViewAdapter.kt
class TaskRecyclerViewAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val db: DatabaseHandler
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    private var taskList: MutableList<TaskModel> = db.getAllTasks()

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: TasksRecyclerViewRowBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(task: TaskModel) {
            binding.apply {
                checkBox.isChecked = task.isDone
                taskTextView.text = task.taskText

                checkBox.setOnClickListener {
                    db.updateStatus(task.id.toLong(), checkBox.isChecked)
                    taskList = db.getAllTasks()
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = TasksRecyclerViewRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(taskList[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = taskList.size

    fun addTask(task: TaskModel) {
        db.addTask(task)
        taskList = db.getAllTasks()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun updateTask(task: TaskModel) {
        db.updateTask(task.id.toLong(), task.taskText)
        taskList = db.getAllTasks()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun removeTask(taskId: Int) {
        db.deleteTask(taskId.toLong())
        taskList = db.getAllTasks()
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}

Which approach is better for updating the RecyclerView data when the database is updated?
Are there any best practices or considerations I should be aware of when choosing between these two methods?

As far as best practices go, you should have an additional layer (ViewModel) between activity and your database - there you expose/transform current state of database as flow that is collected in activity as view state. You might also want to consider extending ListAdapter instead to run meaningful update diffs instead of nuking your adapter with notifyDataSetChanged() on every change.

Obviously a MVC programming design. Approach 2 is better, although it is not perfect.
My advice is reusing and modifying MutableList<TaskModel> directly by using position for every query or modification, then update your db, call notifyItemChanged() instead of notifyDataSetChanged() finally.
There is no need to get the latest data from db after modification every time, that is redundant (just query for once while calling init() of TaskRecyclerViewAdapter).

But what if I update the MutableList but the DB update fails. Then this might cause irregularities in UI vs DB. That's why i was updating UI only after DB update

Okay, I got it. But in fact I would rather get the return value from db api (1 or 0?) to check if it takes effect than do query.

Sry i didn't understand completely... can you explain steps in little more detail taking example of updateTask function

Generally, developers use SQLiteDatabase apis provided by Android framework to operate‌ databases. Your wrapper function db.updateTask() should have a return value as int type, likes the public function int update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) in the class SQLiteDatabase. And the returns is
the number of rows affected.

Maybe your db object instantiated from a Class that wraps SQLiteDatabase.
